# Swapping "lines" of a string in python

Tags: python, string

**I have a string that looks like this:**

```
string1 = "Hello" + '\n' + "Smith" +'\n'+ "Jake" +'\n'+ "I am"
print(string1)
```

**This prints out:**

```
Hello
Smith
Jake
I am
```

**However, I would like it to be changed to this:**

```
Hello
I am
Jake
Smith
```

Now some might say to just switch "I am" and "Smith" in your original string but the thing is I can't do that. I need to look for another way to edit the string after.

One clarification: "Smith" could be a different name and "I am" could also be another phrase like "You are". So lines 2 and 4 will not always be "Smith" and "I am" respectively.

**Another test case:**

Original output:

```
Hi,
Doe?
John
Are you
```

Desired output:

```
Hi,
Are you
John
Doe?
```

**Essentially I need something that can swap the fourth line of the string with the second line.**

Basically I've tried to split the string on '\n' into a list and then swap the values in the list and then rejoining the list with '\n' but it's really ugly. I am wondering if there is a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> one, two, three, four = string1.splitlines()
>>> '\n'.join((one, four, three, two))
'Hello\nI am\nJake\nSmith'
```

Or this?

```
>>> lines = string1.splitlines()
>>> '\n'.join([lines[0], *reversed(lines[1:])])
'Hello\nI am\nJake\nSmith'
```

Or this?

```
>>> lines = string1.splitlines()
>>> lines[1:] = reversed(lines[1:])
>>> '\n'.join(lines)
'Hello\nI am\nJake\nSmith'
```

Or this?

```
>>> lines = string1.splitlines()
>>> lines[1], lines[3] = lines[3], lines[1]
>>> '\n'.join(lines)
'Hello\nI am\nJake\nSmith'
```

Comment: yooo that first one is kinda hott i like it, thanks bro, okay let's say it has 8 rows and I need to swap the 6 and eight row how would that change things AND the 2nd and fourth row? do I put it in a loop?

Comment: I'd use the last one instead, then you can just change the indices.

Comment: sorry I forgot to edit, but I mean I still have to swap 2 and 4 and 6 and 8 etc. so on so forth until my factor of 4 lines are all swapped

Comment: That's a different problem of course. I'd use the last one in a loop then.

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = "Hello" + '\n' + "Smith" +'\n'+ "Jake" +'\n'+ "I am"
phrases = string1.split("\n")
phrases[1], phrases[3] = phrases[3], phrases[1]
print("\n".join(phrases))
```

Comment: yea that's what I did but I said it was too messy

Comment: @Thomas's answer is way cleaner, for sure. I was already typing when he posted his answer.

Comment: okay thank you, but one more question: let's say it has 8 rows and I need to swap the 6 and eight row how would that change things AND the 2nd and 4th row? do I put it in a loop?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You want to swap the 6th with the 8th, and the 2nd with the 4th? In that case, one swap doesn't affect the other.